# Cumulative cross addition/multiplication in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication, scientific-computing

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6]

c = [1*2, 1*4 + 2*2, 1*6 + 2*4 + 3*2]
```

I have done using dot product by creating Toeplitz matrix but I am looking for a much faster version since I am dealing with a huge dataset. Using loop will also slow down computation.

Comment: Show your code that works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This output is the first half of a convolution of `a` and `b`:

```
numpy.convolve(a, b)[:len(a)]
```

If your arrays are big enough, you may be able to save time with an FFT-based convolution:

```
scipy.signal.fftconvolve(a, b)[:len(a)]
```

An FFT convolution has runtime `O(n log n)` where `n` is the length of the input arrays, in contrast to the `O(n^2)` runtime of a straightforward nested-loop convolution. However, it has a worse constant factor, and it requires floating-point arithmetic, so results may have a small amount of numerical error.

On a sufficiently recent version of SciPy (at least 0.19.0, [released March 09, 2017](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/index.html)), you can use [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html#scipy.signal.convolve) to automatically pick between a direct or FFT convolution based on an estimate of which would be faster. Prior to 0.19.0, `scipy.signal.convolve` would always use a direct computation.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I used `b = [4,5,6]` instead of `[2,4,6]`.

Comment: `scipy.signal.convolve` by default _"Automatically chooses direct or Fourier method based on an estimate of which is faster"_

Comment: @PaulPanzer: It does?.. ah, I see, "New in version 0.19.0."

Comment: @PradeepTummala: If you have a new question, post a new question. Don't keep asking for more in an existing question.